# How to get Application Insights operation id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure Function app written in javascript that has Application Insights integrated:

```
const AppInsights = require("applicationinsights");

AppInsights.setup(appInsightsInstrumentationKey);
AppInsights.defaultClient.context.tags[
    AppInsights.defaultClient.context.keys.cloudRole
        ] = "My back-end";
AppInsights.start();
```

The module version is 1.7.4.

I do need to access the current operation id to send it to my custom log for correlation with AI logs in Azure. In my functions I tried this:

```
var telemetry = appInsights.defaultClient;
var oid = telemetry.context.tags["ai.operation.id"]; // does not work
var oid = telemetry.context.operation.id; // does not work
```

Nevertheless, AI collects it somehow so I can see it in Azure portal:

[image]

How can I access `operation_id` value at run-time in my Azure functions?

Answer (score 2):

You can give it a try with this line of code:

```
//operation id
var s = client.context.keys["operationId"];
```

I found it via debug, the screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: In this case `s` will contain "ai.operation.id" - the key to lookup operation id value and in my case `.context.tags["ai.operation.id"]` is not defined :(

Comment: It might help to access the tag via the key value like
`client.context.tags[client.context.keys.operationId]`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Azure Functions, but in a node js application I am able to use:

```
const AppInsights = require("applicationinsights");
var context = AppInsights.getCorrelationContext();
var oid = context.operation.id;
```

Guaranteed to work in module version 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation in nodejs client, I think you have to set the `setDistributedTracingMode` to `appInsights.DistributedTracingModes.AI`

That is  what operationId is doing, it helps tracking distributed systems so you can correlate requests.

From the [documentation page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights):

```
let appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup("<instrumentation_key>")
    .setDistributedTracingMode(appInsights.DistributedTracingModes.AI)
    .start();
```

The operationId is a value that is added on every request automatically by the Application Insights SDK but apparently in a later stage, when you try to access it is early too yet. That is the problem with black box solutions. But you can try to set it yourself in first place. Set telemetry.context.operation.id to be a unique id yourself and confirm if this is tracked by the ApplicationInsights properly.

Comment: I have it enabled explicitly and it doesn't work. I'm more interested in the code on how to access the operationid value.

Comment: @UserControl the operationId is a value that is added on every request automatically by the Application Insights SDK but apparently in a later stage, when you try to access it is early too yet. That is the problem with black box solutions. Try to set it yourself! Set  telemetry.context.operation.id to be a unique id yourself and confirm if this is tracked by the ApplicationInsights properly.

Comment: @UserControl since you are using an azure function app I suppose that this is the beginning of the operation, so it is the place where operation_id is autogenerated. If you had a web application things would be easier to access it. But try the suggestion above, it should work

Comment: @Stellios, I tried it and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @UserControl I am out of ideas if that did not work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#context-object) you can access or edit operation id by calling `context.executionContext.invocationId`.