# Need help and guidance for accessing operationId in nodejs application

Tags: node.js, react-native, azure-application-insights

We are using nodejs as my backend application and react native in front end. And azure application insights for logging. In UI side, we are redirecting to Stripe checkout page(external page) for payment and then coming back to our application's confirmation page. Here we are loosing the flow on end-to-end transaction. My requirement is to link pre-stripe and post-stripe operation into one single flow. For this my approach of solving this problem is accessing OPERATIONID and pass it to stripe and receive it back from Stripe and use it in confirmation page so that we will one single flow. I Need help in guiding me to the right documentation/ solution proposals.

I read some articles(eg: [How to get Application Insights operation id in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959072/how-to-get-application-insights-operation-id-in-javascript)) and figured out that operationId is a uniqueID which gets created out of my application and cant access it in the application. I tried to use below code and got response of that operationID as "ai.operation.id" but seems like this is not the right pattern(value) of operationId.

```
import { defaultClient } from 'applicationinsights';
 const telemetryClient = defaultClient;
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
  console.log(telemetryClient.context.keys[`operationId`]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The main function of operationId is to help tracking distributed systems so you can correlate requests. So as given in this [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights#:%7E:text=Distributed%20Tracing%20Modes) in nodejs client, you should set the `setDistributedTracingMode` to `appInsights.DistributedTracingModes.AI_AND_W3C` as shown below.

```js
const appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights
  .setup("<your ikey>")
  .setDistributedTracingMode(appInsights.DistributedTracingModes.AI_AND_W3C)
  .start()
```

You should be able to get the operation id using the following code snippet.

```js
const AppInsights = require("applicationinsights");
var context = AppInsights.getCorrelationContext();
var oid = context.operation.id;
```

If it does not solve your problem then, I would suggest you to set **`telemetry.context.operation.id`** to be a unique id by yourself and confirm if this is tracked by the Application Insights properly.

Also note that the latest version of the JavaScript SDK (SDK v2) for Application Insights have some changes as given in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#upgrading-from-the-old-version-of-application-insights).

> Moved `context.operation` to `context.telemetryTrace`. Some fields were also changed (`operation.id` --> `telemetryTrace.traceID`).
> To keep the trace ID unique, where you previously used `Util.newId()`, now use `Util.generateW3CId()`. Both ultimately end up being the operation ID.

For more information read this [log custom telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#log-custom-telemetry) document.